# Can I Make Glass with just Pure Quartz Sand and Magical Heat Powers?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction

Okay, I've been researching how to make Glass for a character with powers that include Sand and Heat. But, I keep getting results about soda–lime glass/soda–lime–silica glass. Along with purities of the sand and such. When I want to see if it could be done with just pure sand and heat.

Now! If one had pure Quartz Sand/Silica Sand, the ability to manipulate that sand and the resulting glass with a fine mystical control, and enough heat to throw at it in a controlled fine heat manipulating way that it just heats the sand ...

Then could if you had that pure sand, just throw enough heat at it, and then do heat manipulation and what still counts as Sand manipulation of what is now glass to cool it? That is, by mystically manipulating the glass on an atomic level when making things out of that glass.

And would that glass be clear, or would it be cloudy?

Do I need to just have sand powers (that extend to glass powers) and heat powers to make this work? Or do I need to cheat *more* with **more** Space Magic in this Science-Fantasy setting?

Comment: What do the 2nd and 3rd period try to mean?

Comment: I do not understand the question. [Fused quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fused_quartz) (a.k.a. quartz glass) is a real and quite common material. It is not even very expensive expensive, unless you want it really really pure. It can have very nice optical properties.

Comment: P.S. Sand is any material consisting of solid particles between 1⁄16 mm and 2 mm in diameter. While indeed most of the sand in this world contains a lot of silica (a,k,a, quartz), sand consisting *only* of silica is very rare. You may want to find special pure quartz sand, or else accept that your fused sand glass will be very much less than pure.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying ot make, how you cool the glass matters a lot.  look up annealing glass.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes they can, but it will take a while.

You can make glass out of pure silica it just requires a lot more heat (4000 F+)and is harder to work with. that is why soda ash is added. If they are using some kind of telekenisis and normal fire they do have to worry about air bubbles which will keep the glass from being transparent. but if the heat is magic they will not have to worry about air bubbles which are a product of the smoke and gasses from the fire.

Made right pure silica glass (fused quartz) is optically clearer and stronger and more heat resistant than normal glass. It is also much better at handling temperature shock than normal glass. But depending on what you make with it, you still can't just let it cool down in air, you have to anneal it. Which means cooling most of the way (1800F) in an oven over several hours so it can cool evenly. It can then cool to room temperature normally even quenched in water. Fused quartz is much more forgiving than normal glass but it still has to be annealed because the outside cools faster than the inside.

Answer (score 0):

**SORT OF, BUT NOT REALLY**

I imagine that having both sand and heat powers wouldn't innately grant glass powers, but creation of very precise and intricate glass structures would absolutely be in the realm of possibility with practice and training. I mean that not in a "I can just do it because of raw talent" kind of way, but in the way a real craftsman has to hone their skills. Some will be better at other specific creations than others. **So they wouldn't have glass powers per say, but they would have all the tools built in to become one hell of a glazier.** Could they make simple things like glass tableware or daggers in a matter of moments? Yeah probably. Could they make intricate structure like scale models of a castle or a perfectly detailed, life size sculpture of their loved ones? Maybe with a few days of uninterrupted focus.